# SQL Query with AVG(DATEDIFF) and CASE

Tags: sql, case, datediff, duration

I try to calculate a average duration time (days) from data of my table. In this table i have three columns:

1. audit_process_completed (This is the end date / Format: YYYY-MM-DD)
2. audit_decision_date (This is the start date / Format: YYYY-MM-DD)
3. audit_created (This is the ****alternative** start date if 'audit_decision_date' (2.) = '0000-00-00'**

I want to calculate now the time difference in days between 1 and 2 (if not '0000-00-00') or 3 (if 2. is '0000-00-00'). I tried to define the correct start date with a SQL `CASE` before i start the `AVG(DATEDIFF)`. Please check attempt. I am not able to find the right solution for this.

```
SELECT audit_created, audit_decision_date, audit_process_completed
CASE audit_decision_date WHEN '0000-00-00' THEN audit_created ELSE audit_decision_date END AS start_date
(SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF (audit_process_completed, start_date)) AS duration 
FROM audit WHERE general_audit_status = 'Abgeschlossen' AND assigned_auditor = 2
```

Sample Data:

| id | audit_process_completed | audit_decision_date | audit_created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-22 | 2021-01-17 | 2021-01-17 |
| 2 | 2021-01-27 | 0000-00-00 | 2021-01-20 |
| 3 | 2021-01-28 | 0000-00-00 | 2021-01-22 |
| 4 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-01-24 |

**Desired output:**
AVG Duration time in days over the whole table.

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I have added some sample data. I am not sure what you mean with database tag. The datas are all in the same table. The problem is: i am able to do the DATE(DIFF with the 'audit_created' date without any problem. But i want to use the 'decision_date' if it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you seem to want `case` logic for the `avg()`:

```
select avg(datediff( audit_process_completed,
                     (case when audit_decision_date <> '0000-00-00' then audit_decision_date else audit_created end)
                   )
          )
from audit 
where general_audit_status = 'Abgeschlossen' and
      assigned_auditor = 2
```

Comment: Thank you! I was close but was thinking too complicate. Many thanks!